# Get input from edittext using an anonymous class, android

Tags: java, android, math

Long story short I an trying to make an app to convert `Celsius` to `Fahrenheit` and back. I want to get input from an edit text so I can use that for my math, but I can't figure it out, nor can I get the button to work right to close it.  I want to use an internal anonymous class to do the calculations and read in the value, but again no idea what to do. Does anyone have any idea where to start?

here is what I have

```
package com.example.a4;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
 import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

 public class MainActivity extends Activity implements TextWatcher {

EditText mt=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.et1), 
         mt2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.et2);

Button bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //mt=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.et1);
   // mt2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.et2);
}

OnClickListener oclBtnOk = new OnClickListener() {


    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
  };


 /* 
   buttonExit.setOnClickListener(
       new View.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(View v) {
               System.exit(0);
        }
    }
);*/


@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int c = Integer.parseInt(s.toString());

    ftoc(c);

}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
        int after) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


 void ftoc(int c){
  int f = ((9/5)*c) + 32;

  mt2.setText(f);
 }



 /*
  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
      return true;
  }
  */



 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your `mt = (EditText)findViewById` stuff back to onCreate. Then, if you want to use anonymous classes, do something like:

```
mt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View v) {
          ...
     }
});
```

Also, make sure you're using `View.OnClickListener` and not `DialogInterface.OnClickListener` as you are now (check your imports).